# Best practices for an embeddable JS widget; Query script parent server on each load, or work independently?

Tags: javascript, database, performance, embed

I'm building a Javascript widget as an extension to one of my existing web applications. Our users will be able to embed this widget onto their website via a simple script tag with an attached API key.

For example: `<script src="https://example.com/widget.js" data-example="*API_KEY*"></script>`.

The properties of the widget are that the style and functionality can be customised via the user dashboard within the web application, then when they embed the code on their website it will output said widget. For this widget I cannot use iFrame due to it's purpose.

What I'm trying to find out is, in terms of performance, security and general best practises what is the best way to do this. I have some ideas below, and would like to know if there are better ways or even a standard way of doing this.

1. When the example.com/widget.js is called. It will grab the API key then query the backend MVC. A route would be called that will verify the API key, the website host/URL then get the widget configuration settings and display it to the end user.

Questions raised with this method are that every time the widget is called my server will be called which may cause performance issues. Would need extreme caching, rate limiting and IP verification to ensure under high-demand spread over multiple websites so our server performance is not drastically degraded.

2. Make the embed code more independent so the widget is configured using JSON variables on the client side. Meaning all the styling and config options are already on the client side and my server will only verify the api key initially and domain before allowing the widget to be displayed.

Questions raised with this method are that the code of the widget could be manipulated/taken since the config is all there on the client side.

Thoughts?